# Git Mirroring Issue

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a local server running GitLab that all of our on-site developers use.  We also have a github account set up for remote developers.  I need a way to keep github and gitlab in sync with one another.  Does anyone know of any tools/procedures/configs to do this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post-update hook on source repo.

steps - 
exchange keys from source -> dest.

in post-update hook add line like

```
git push --mirror git@dest.example.com/reponame.git
```

assuming - source side repository name is "reponame"
repositories names are consistent across source.example.com and dest.example.com

Comment: can you give me a more in-depth answer as to how to accomplish this?  I am still a novice with Git.

Comment: and yes, the repo names will be consistent.

Comment: Establish public key auth between git@source.example.com git@des.example.com.  You need to modify post-update hook with above command and give +x permission. Hooks are kept in reponame/.git/hooks.  Every time you push anything to source.example.com, after successful update, this cascades same delta to dest.example.com

Comment: so this goes on each individual dev machine?  Or on the local server?

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks so much.